# Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, factoring

I know that an Euclidean ring is a principal ring and this last is a factorial ring.

I also know that if $B$ is a field, then $B[x]$ is Euclidean. While, for instance $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a principal ring, while it is factorial (since $\mathbb{Z}$ is factorial).

Is there an example of a commutative ring with unity $R$ such that $R[x]$ is a principal ring but not an Euclidean one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such example, because if the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is a PID, then $R$ is a field, so that $R[x]$ is also Euclidean. For references see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain).